# QNX's shutdown_system is not function well when ZMQ lib is used

Tags: zeromq, qnx, system-shutdown

When QNX's `shutdown_system()` is called from command line (`shutdown`) or from within any process, it's expected to restart the system,
when called as `shutdown_system(SHUTDOWN_REBOOT, 0);`

There are several processes running on our QNX system. For interproces communication we are using `libzmq`.

When `shutdown_system` is called from command line, it is working all good. The system is restarted [as expected.](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/s/shutdown_system.html)

But when the `shutdown_system` is called from a particular process ( when `libzmq` calls are enabled ) what is observed is that the process from which `shutdown_system` is called is killed and the QNX system goes off network. But all other processes are running well on QNX system.

I commented all zmq's related calls and rerun the system, this time `shutdown_system` when called from within a process restarts the system as expected.

Something in ZeroMQ is stopping the `SIGTERM | SIGKILL` to other process and also stopping the restart of the system. I tried disconnecting the ZeroMQ connection before issuing the `system_shutdown` in process, but it did not help.